# How to inherit page appearance?

Tags: angularjs

I have a few pages in my website.
I have a general frame for my website: Top, bottom, and general css are the same for all pages.
What is the convenient way to share the frame between all pages, so that they all look the same.

Comment: Are you using `ng-view`?

Comment: I could use it. So this is the recommended way I assume?

Comment: It's the "angular way". As you are using angularjs (assuming by your question tag), you should go for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *AngularJS way* to achieve this is by the use of `ng-view` and routes.

For this, you must include the `angular-route` file and inject `ngRoute` in your app. Follow the example:

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ata-ng-app="myApp">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>My App</title>
</head>
<body>
  <header><h1> Header for all pages </h1></header>

  <div data-ng-view></div> <!-- your files will be rendered here -->

  <footer>...</footer>

  <script src="path/to/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="path/to/angular-route.min.js"></script>
  <script src="path/to/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**app.js**

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute'])
  .controller('PageCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.title = "The Title";
  }])
  .config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
      when("/", {
        templateUrl: "path/to/page.html",
        controller: "PageCtrl"
      }).
   }]);
```

**page.html**

```
<h3> {{ scope.title }} </h3>
```